# source bash string instead of file

Tags: bash, shell, source

I want to source a bash function from a string instead of a file at the command line, so instead of this:

```
source file.sh
```

I want to do something like:

```
source `cat <<EOF
   some_func(){
   echo "nodejs version: $(node --version)"
   echo "r2g version: $(r2g --version)"
   echo "npm version: $(npm --version)"
   }
   export -f some_func;
EOF`
```

is this possible somehow?

Comment: Why jump through so many hoops? Just put the text into the code right there?

Comment: yeah actually what might be convenient is to send it all to the clipboard

Comment: Why not define your function in a shell startup file?

Comment: because the user is going to copy the code and paste in their terminal, but the code will be in a readme file or Github issue template

Comment: `source <( cat <<END ... )`, but it seem like an awfully fragile and awkward workflow. I won't write this as an answer because I think it's ugly.

Comment: This is good because instead of "curl -L https:dom.top/install.sh | bash" which won't result in stuff affecting the current login shell, "source <( curl -L https:dom.top/install.sh )" will affect aliases and the likes in the shell after without saving the file to disk when you might prefer it private, so thanks.

Comment: it has it's rare use cases, but for some reason this didn't work - I would expect foo to be "bar" `source <(echo "export foo=bar");
echo "$foo"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These work on Bash 4 but not Bash 3 -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source <(echo "export foo=bar");
echo "$foo"

source <(cat <<< "export foo=bar");
echo "$foo"

source <(cat <<EOF
  export foo=bar
EOF
);
echo "$foo"
```

perhaps `source` and `.` cannot read from a file descriptor?

Comment: All three works for me.

Comment: I think it's just a Bash 3 vs 4 issue, Bash v3 strikes again

Comment: Why is this posted as an answer, and not an edit to the question? It explicitly says none of these worked.

Comment: @muru see updates I just made